# Generate sample values of a distribution with known Characteristic Function in R

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

I have given the characteristic function
$$\mathcal F(p)(x)=\frac{\exp(-|x|^s)}{(1 + x^2)^5}$$
where $s=0.5, s=1, s=1.5$ or $s=2$.

Now I want to get sample values of the distribution belonging to the density $p$.

Since the inverse Fourier transform does not exist in closed form one way to get samples would be using numerical methods. A well-known method is "Inverse transform sampling" but for this I would need the inverse CDF and it is a long way to get there (CF->PDF->CDF->InvCDF).

Does anyone know a better algorithm to generate a sample? My paper refers to the properties of $\alpha$-stable random variables.

Comment: If you're going for numerical methods, maybe you can approximate the Fourier transform itself by a sufficiently precise quadrature formula, remapping $(0, +\infty)$ (I'd rather avoid the non-smoothness at zero) to a finite interval by a rational or meromorphic substitution?

Comment: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358524/sampling-from-characteristic-moment-generating-function) also seems to be related to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The link to Gi_F.'s program rdevroye.r helped a lot :) I immidiatly get the result by typing
rdevroye(10,function(x){exp(-abs(x)^s)/ (1 + x^2)^5})

Comment: Hm, doesn't it compute inverse Laplace transform instead of inverse Fourier?

Comment: Yes, but it should work if i one repleaces x with 1*i*x